# Limiting MySQL results to prior days of the week

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like so:

```
id | gallons_used | date
----------------------
1    2             157263300
2    5             157262000
...
```

I want to get a result set containing only records that took place on X day of the week (Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday, etc etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DAYNAME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) in your `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) = 'Monday'  <-- by day of the week
  AND `date` < INTERVAL CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAY     <-- within the last week
```

You can use [`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) as well but this is more readable.

Comment: `date` is a Unix timestamp. Will need a conversion first.

Comment: Correct. I overlooked that. Fixed.

Comment: Don't you also need one around the second `date`?

Answer (score 0):

Something that would check for Wednesday as an example given that your `date` column is a timestamp:

```
DAYOFWEEK(date) = 4
```

Reference to documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12762/3

I had a `FROM_UNIXTIME()` call around date as well but I don't think it is required(not 100% sure). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Unix timestamp, you can use the following:

```
SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)
FROM ...
WHERE DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) = 'Monday'
  AND `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800
```

### [See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bfc2/3)